# How do you password protect static content in JBoss 3 with Jetty 4?

Tags: jboss, jetty

I have a login app which relies on webtoken and cookies, and a few other apps running in jboss. I also have static content mostly PDF files under apache2 which are listed in a static page as links, which can be accessed directly without credentials. I'm trying to password protect these content, and willing to move them somewhere in my jboss. So that If I try to access the url to a specific PDF file, and I'm not logged in, I shoud be redirect to login. If I'm logged in i should be able to see the PDF file opened in my browser.

Spec:
jboss-3.2.7
jetty-4.2.24 sar

Comment: What is `jetty-4.2.24.sar`??

Comment: that was the old service archive file that would run in early jboss...circa 2002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a filter with authentication and filter mapping with url pattern in WEB-INF web.xml.

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>filter1</filter-name>
 <filter-class>com.shojib.filter1</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>filter1</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/htdocs/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```